# How to calculate count of occurence of each value from a list column of Pandas efficiently?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas data frame, which looks like the following:

```
      df =
                  col1

                  ['a', 'b']
                  ['d', 'c', 'a']
                  ['b', 'f', 'a']
```

`col1` is a list column, which contains strings. I want to calculate value counts of each element, which may occur in any of the lists in any row. Expected output is a dictionary, of counts of each value

**Expected Output**

```
      df_dict = {'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 1, 'd': 1, 'f': 1}
```

How to do this efficiently in 1 line preferably to make the code clean. Sorry, if it has been answered before.

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `explode` and `value_counts`:

```
df['col1'].explode().value_counts().to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 1, 'f': 1, 'c': 1}
```